# Is it necessary to move a private class within an .aspx page to AppCode folder as a new .cs file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Imagine a class that will be used only for internal operations within a web-form or a user control.

Is there any disadvantages from the compiler point of view to introduce a class in the AppCode separately than declaring it inside the .aspx or .ascx as a private class.

Answer (score 1):

So long as the user control itself is not stored in the `App_Code` folder, there a no disadvantages to placing your classes in there, in fact, it's desired - that's what it is for.

I think the main reason for the placement of code files within the `App_Code` folder is simply down to a couple of factors:

- A conventional containing folder to store code
- Relevant permissions applied by default so that your code files aren't browsable (at least)

I'm sure there'll be more benefits which an expert can explain, but generally I would advise you extract such classes from the web site / application and house such code in a dedicated compiled class library anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no disadvantage, if your code is independent of the aspx/ascx, it is better to create it under the AppCode folder as a separate file.
You might also want to consider creating a separate class project for placing all your reusable classes so that they can be shared between multiple web applications.